# Ajax not responding to select drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter framework, I am trying to create a drop down list for categories that has subcategories and that subcategories have subcategories and so on...So when the user chooses a first level of category say 'Men' on a drop down list, another drop down list will appear below and I can choose t-shirts and another drop down list will appear say long sleeves and it goes on until how deep it is.

I have created a table with the column name: id, category_name and parent_id and was able to retrieve it:

```
public function get_categories($parent_id = 0){
  $this->db->from('all_categories');
  $this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
  $result = $this->db->get();
  return $result->result_array();
}
```

I then have the initial drop down that retrieves all the rows that has parent_id = 0

```
<select class="theTarget">
  <?php
  echo "<option>Select Category</option>";
  foreach($getCategories as $row){
  echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">". $row['category_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select> 
<div class="subCategories">
//subcategories will appear here...
</div>
```

Looking good so far..

Now in my script I have:

```
$('form').on('change','.theTarget',function(){
    //Gets the value of the selected
    var categoryId = $('.theTarget option:selected').val();
    $.post('fetch_subcategories',{categoryId:categoryId}, function(data){
        $('.subCategories').html(data);
    });

});
```

Then ajax posts to the file fetch_subcategories.php with posts info. In the fetch_subcategories.php I have this:

```
$categoryId = $_POST['categoryId'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM all_categories WHERE parent_id = {$categoryId}";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$html = "
        <select class='theTarget'>
            <option>Select Subcategory</option>
        ";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $html .="<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['category_name']."</option>";
            }   
        $html .= "</select>";

if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
    echo $html; 
}
```

Great still looking good! It does exactly what I want it todo. I chose Men then a drop down appears and there is t-shirt... but when i chose t-shirt (the t-shirt also has subcategory) nothing happens.

This is the longest post I have ever posted and this is driving me nuts. What am I missing here? Or if anyone can suggest a better way of doing this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can we see the entire form in a jsFiddle or jsBin please?

Comment: Right, I will get on with that, however I have never used jsfiddle, will try that now

Comment: does jsfiddle or jsbin run php and sql? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: When using jsFiddle or jsBin, you don't copy the PHP scripts, only the source HTML as you would see if you selected `View Source` in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your JavaScript function to this:

```
$('form').on('change','.theTarget',function(){
    //Gets the value of the selected
    var categoryId = $(this).val();
    $.post('fetch_subcategories',{categoryId:categoryId}, function(data){
        $(this).after(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: This kind of helped me, I had to tweak some stuff, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your **HTML** looks something like this (*please note the changes I have made*):

```
<form>
<div class="categories">
<select class="theTarget" name="department" id="dept">
<option value="0">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">Men</option>
<option value="2">Women</option>
<option value="3">Boys</option>
<option value="4">Girls</option>
<option value="5">Aliens</option>
</select>
</div> 
<div class="subCategories">
<select class="theTarget" name="items" id="item">
<option value="0">Select Category</option>
<option value="1">T-shirts</option>
<option value="2">Hats</option>
<option value="3">Outerwear</option>
<option value="4">Underwear</option>
<option value="5">Socks</option>
</select> 
</div>
</form>
```

And your **jQuery**, as written, is this:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').on('change','.theTarget',function(){
    //Gets the value of the selected
    var categoryId = $('.theTarget option:selected').val();
    $.post('fetch_subcategories',{categoryId:categoryId}, function(data){
        $('.subCategories').html(data);
    });

  });
});
```

Immediately, I see an issue because both dropdowns have the same class `theTarget`. So, no matter which dropdown you choose a new option for, the script will run. I would change your script to look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').on('change','#dept',function(){
    //Gets the value of the selected
    var categoryId = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $.post('fetch_subcategories.php',{categoryId:categoryId}, function(data){
        $('.subCategories').html(data);
    });

  });
  $('form').on('change','#item',function(){
    //Gets the value of the selected
    var categoryId = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $.post('fetch_subsubcategories.php',{categoryId:categoryId}, function(data){
        $('.subsubCategories').html(data);
    });
    .... and so on ....
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple add this function to your javascript

```
function show_dropdown() {
  $("form .theTarget").off("change").on("change", function() {
    var select  = $(this);
    var cat_id  = select.val();
    select.nextAll(".theTarget").remove();
    $.post( 'fetch_subcategories.php', { categoryId : cat_id }, function( data ) {
      if ( data ) {
        $(data).insertAfter( select );
        show_dropdown();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

then call this in dom ready event..

```
$(function() {
  show_dropdown();
});
```

and your html will be

```
<form>
  <select class="theTarget">
    <?php
      echo "<option>Select Category</option>";
      foreach( $getCategories as $row ) {
        echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">". $row['category_name']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

**Note: you no longer need the `<div class="subCategories">` element**